# Wildfly: authorization fails after server restart

Tags: java, maven, soap, wildfly

I first do the setup needed (described below). Everything works, but when I restart `standalone.sh` and do a SOAP request I only get this response:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>Unauthorized</body>
</html>
```

And in the terminal with `standalone.sh` I get:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.security] (default task-1) PBOX00261: Failed to load users/passwords/roles files: java.io.IOException: PBOX00072: Properties file users.properties/defaultUsers.properties not found
```

What should I do to make the authorization work?

## Setup

This is what I do to setup everything:

1. I run `mvn archetype:generate` and create the project from `org.wildfly.archetype:wildfly-javaee7-webapp-ear-blank-archetype` archetype

groupId: pl.edu.agh.soa

artifactId: lab

2. I create a class `Hello.java` in `lab/lab-ejb/src/main/java/pl/edu/agh/soa`:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
@SecurityDomain("domain1")
@DeclareRoles({"developer"})
@WebContext(
   authMethod="BASIC",
   transportGuarantee="NONE")
public class Hello {

    private List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @WebMethod
    @RolesAllowed("developer")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="subjects")
    @XmlElement(name="subject")
    public List<String>
    listSubjects(@WebParam(name="filter") String filter) {
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String elem : this.subjects) {
            if(elem.contains(filter)) {
                filtered.add(elem);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    @WebMethod
    @RolesAllowed("developer")
    @WebResult
    public String
    addSubject(@WebParam(name="subj") String subj) {
        this.subjects.add(subj);
        return "After add: " + this.subjects.toString();
    }

    @WebMethod
    @RolesAllowed("developer")
    @WebResult
    public String
    editName(String name) {
        String before = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        
        return "Before: " + before;
    }

    @WebMethod
    @RolesAllowed("developer")
    @WebResult
    public String
    editSurname(String surname) {
        String before = this.surname;
        this.surname = surname;
        
        return "Before: " + before;
    }
}
```

3. I add `user3` with add-user.sh
4. Create a new security domain with `jboss-cli.sh`, there I paste:

`/subsystem=security/security-domain=domain1/:add(cache-type=default)`

`/subsystem=security/security-domain=domain1/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"UsersRoles","flag"=>"required","module-options"=>[("usersProperties"=>"users.properties"),("rolesProperties"=>"roles.properties")]}])`

5. I create `users.properties` and `roles.properties` files in `lab/lab-ejb/src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the `roles.properties` and `users.properties` in another directory e.g. : `\wildfly-20.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration` or `src/main/resources`

[check the security documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#Security_Realms)

Comment: Putting these files into `src/main/resources` did work. Thanks a lot!